# QWidget sizeHint()

Tags: c++, qt, qwidget

i have reimplemented(overloaded) a `sizeHint()` function in a customized `QPushButton` class like this:

```
QSize CustQPushButton::sizeHint()const         
{
   QWidget *parentWindow=this->parentWidget(); //a pointer to the parent window   
  return QSize(parentWindow->width()/10,60);
}
```

the problem is :

When the window is initially displayed the width of my buttons are as expected(1/10 the window), but when the window is resized the 
buttons are not resized proportionally to the window(the parent). The `CustQPushButton` Size Policy is set to `Fixed/Fixed` and my instantiated buttons are inside a QGridLayout.

Can someone please help me?

Comment: I do not think you want fixed. I am thinking expanding or preferred.

Comment: actually i want fixed.i want the width-hint of my buttons be function of the parent-window width proportionally.

Comment: Make parent resizeEvent to call adjustSize for all CustQPushButton buttons.

Comment: i tried to implement your code "AlexanderVX" but it's unpredictable too : initially the buttons are quite, then they get overlapped when resizing the window.thanks for the idea.

Comment: maybe try if a combination of [layouts](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/layout.html) and minimum/maximum sizes will not do what you're trying to achieve, instead of overloading the sizeHint?

Comment: coucou8949, if not the answer below than the setFixedSize with specific size for your buttons from that same event handler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need custom classes for such a trivial thing. Purpose of size hint is entirely different. Default layouts can handle 1/10 width. You should use `QGridLayout::setColumnStretch` function. For example, setting stretch factors of two columns to 1 and 9 will resize 1st column to 1/10 of parent (assuming content of the 2nd column can grow enough).

Comment: stretching enables a constant scaling between columns or raws,while i understand what you mean still i don't think it's appropriate, in the link below, towards the middle of the page you'll find a section named :"Adding Widgets to a Layout"  witch tells that layouts arrange widgets next to their size policy and size hint first after what it takes account of the stretching factor.thank you. http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/layout.html